# How do I save the user's date, time, and ip whenever they log in to my system?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In my `users` table, there is the following column: `day_visit`,`visit_time` and `last_ip`

I am using codeigniter 3, but I am having difficulty creating the function to track this user information whenever he logs into my system.

I have the Auth controller and the Model Auth_model should I create the function on my controller and list it in view?

Comment: In your modal when you are checking if the email/username and password are correct then after validating it, just get the id of the user and run an update query to update those details.

Answer (score 1):

for ip, visit_time and day_visit use below `function`

```
ipaddress:  $this->input->ip_address();
visit_time: $time = time();
day_visit: date('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collect user information when he login to the system.

For IP you can use Codeigniter pre-defined input function.

```
$ip = $this->input->ip_address();
```

For visit time you can use `time()` function and for visit day you can use `date('Y-m-d')`.

Comment: @SavajPatel I think if someone gave the answer and coincidently another person gave the answer and coincidently both are same. that is not copying the answer. and if I am copying the answer, can you please tell us what is the correct answer and should not be the same as I have commented.

Comment: yes but everyone represent are different thing not as same as the someone i think so 50 to 60 percent  same but not logic are doing same.

Comment: you can get all thing using this code too `echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$now = new DateTime();
echo "<br/>";
echo $now->format('Y-m-d');
echo "<br/>";
echo $now->format('H:i:s');` his not mention on specific way they need only way for store information and be polite for talk.